# How to add the current date to a html file using batch file

Tags: html, batch-file

I have an html file with some data and there is a line there:

```
<span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"'><span style='color:gray'>&nbsp;January 1, 2013</span></span>
```

Is there a way to use a batch file to replace the date there with current date?

Comment: Why from a batch file? Is there a reason why you dont want to use Php or Javascript to grab todays date? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
Using  `<?php echo date("Y/m/d"); ?>` will print todays date for you...

Comment: [SSI](http://www.ssi-developer.net/ssi/ssi-date.shtml) springs to mind too.

Answer (score 0):

Save this as a `bat`

```
 @if (@x)==(@y) @end /***** jscript comment ******
 @echo off
 for /f "delims=" %%d in ('cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"') do set "c_date=%%d"
 echo ^<span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"'^>^<span style='color:gray'^>^&nbsp;%c_date%^</span^>^</span^>
 exit /b 0
 *****  end comment *********/

 var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
 var now = new Date();
 var formated=  monthNames[now.getMonth()] + " " + now.getDay() +", "+ now.getFullYear();
 WScript.Echo(formated);
```

**EDIT**

```
 @if (@x)==(@y) @end /***** jscript comment ******
 @echo off
 for /f "delims=" %%d in ('cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"') do set "c_date=%%d"
 echo ^<span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"'^>^<span style='color:gray'^>^&nbsp;%c_date%^</span^>^</span^>

 setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 for /f "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("My_html_file") do (
    setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
    (echo("%%l")|findstr /i /r /c:"<span style='font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\"'><span style='color:gray'>&nbsp;.*</span></span>" >nul 2>&1&& echo ^<span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"'^>^<span style='color:gray'^>^&nbsp;%c_date%^</span^>^</span^>
    (echo("%%l")|findstr /i /r /c:"<span style='font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\"'><span style='color:gray'>&nbsp;.*</span></span>" >nul 2>&1|| (echo(%%l)

 ) >> temp.html


 exit /b 0
 *****  end comment *********/

 var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
 var now = new Date();
 var formated=  monthNames[now.getMonth()] + " " + now.getDay() +", "+ now.getFullYear();
 WScript.Echo(formated);
```

Comment: yes.Didn't read the question carefully.Will update the answer.This technique is not invented by me..

Comment: I get an error, maybe because of Jscript. do I need it to be installed somewhere?

Comment: what error?. You don't need to install anything.Every windows system has jscript...

Comment: <span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"'><span style='color:gray'>&nbsp;January 4, 2014</span></span> - that is what I got, and nothing happened.

Comment: could you check mu edit? and opent the temp.html to see if this is what you want

Comment: May you know how to help me with replace a string in the file? For now it only prints the right line on the command line window. thanks

Comment: @user1016179 Ok.I will do it.